Help needed in generating a list of radii
I am trying to generate a list of radii between two given points (0 and 1 in this example). Below is my code in Python to generate the list.
radii = []
num_of_annuli = 100
annuli_width = 1/num_of_annuli
radius_values = 0
for i in range (0, 100):
  radius_values = radius_values + annuli_width
  radii.append(radius_values)
print(radii)

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work. See the output below.
[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.060000000000000005, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09999999999999999, 0.10999999999999999, 0.11999999999999998, 0.12999999999999998, 0.13999999999999999, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18000000000000002, 0.19000000000000003, 0.20000000000000004, 0.21000000000000005, 0.22000000000000006, 0.23000000000000007, 0.24000000000000007, 0.25000000000000006, 0.26000000000000006, 0.2700000000000001, 0.2800000000000001, 0.2900000000000001, 0.3000000000000001, 0.3100000000000001, 0.3200000000000001, 0.3300000000000001, 0.34000000000000014, 0.35000000000000014, 0.36000000000000015, 0.37000000000000016, 0.38000000000000017, 0.3900000000000002, 0.4000000000000002, 0.4100000000000002, 0.4200000000000002, 0.4300000000000002, 0.4400000000000002, 0.45000000000000023, 0.46000000000000024, 0.47000000000000025, 0.48000000000000026, 0.49000000000000027, 0.5000000000000002, 0.5100000000000002, 0.5200000000000002, 0.5300000000000002, 0.5400000000000003, 0.5500000000000003, 0.5600000000000003, 0.5700000000000003, 0.5800000000000003, 0.5900000000000003, 0.6000000000000003, 0.6100000000000003, 0.6200000000000003, 0.6300000000000003, 0.6400000000000003, 0.6500000000000004, 0.6600000000000004, 0.6700000000000004, 0.6800000000000004, 0.6900000000000004, 0.7000000000000004, 0.7100000000000004, 0.7200000000000004, 0.7300000000000004, 0.7400000000000004, 0.7500000000000004, 0.7600000000000005, 0.7700000000000005, 0.7800000000000005, 0.7900000000000005, 0.8000000000000005, 0.8100000000000005, 0.8200000000000005, 0.8300000000000005, 0.8400000000000005, 0.8500000000000005, 0.8600000000000005, 0.8700000000000006, 0.8800000000000006, 0.8900000000000006, 0.9000000000000006, 0.9100000000000006, 0.9200000000000006, 0.9300000000000006, 0.9400000000000006, 0.9500000000000006, 0.9600000000000006, 0.9700000000000006, 0.9800000000000006, 0.9900000000000007, 1.0000000000000007]

The expected output is a list [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04...1.0] instead.
Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong? If you have a better, more efficient code to do this job, please share that too.

This seems correct to machine precision. More accuracy could be obtained by summing the from smallest elements to largest

You could also avoid the sum altogether if the annuli are all the same width as they are here: radii =[i*annuli_width for i in range(1,101)]

You could also use numpy, radii = numpy.linspace(0, 1, num_of_annuli+1)
